# "The C standards set lower bounds on the numeric ranges of the different data types, but there are no upper bounds"?

Tags: c, types, architecture, system, limit

While reading my textbook *Computer systems* by Randal E. Bryant & David R. O'Hallaron, I got a question on this:

> The C standards set lower bounds on the numeric ranges of the different data types, 
>       but there are no upper bounds.

What does this mean?

Comment: It means, on some implementation, a data type (`unsigned char` for example) cannot have a range smaller than what the Standard says (`0` to `255` for example), but can have a larger range (`0` to `65535` or `0` to `68719476735` (2^36 - 1))

Comment: There _are_ upper bounds, but they are implementation-defined. An implementation is required to document all the limits.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the C standard for example says that an `int` should be at least large enough to hold the value `-32767` to `32767`, but it may be larger.

In the real world, 16 bit computers use `-32768` to `32767` since they use 2's complement. While 32 bit computers use -2.14 to +2.14 billion.

Comment: so if i designed for int to have  -40000 , then it is not okay but it can be 40000. Is it right?